# File upload script running correctly, but not the file is not in the directory

Tags: php

I'm working with a file upload script that is actually running correctly, yet when I check the directory I'm uploading the file to, it doesn't appear.  What am I doing wrong with my script?

**upload_form.php**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="php/upload.php">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
    <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
$target = "/uploads/";
$path = $target.basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
if($_POST["upload"]){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target)){
        echo "The file has been uploaded.";
    }
    else{
        echo "There was an error.";
    }
}
```

The uploads folder is within the same directory as the upload.php file.  As I mentioned, the script is running completely and correctly because I'm seeing the message associate with the  if statement.  So, what am I doing wrong?  If I change the directory to `uploads/` I get the following errors:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\wamp\www\TouchKiosk-ver2\php\upload.php on line 5
```

and

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php5F6F.tmp' to 'uploads/' in C:\wamp\www\TouchKiosk-ver2\php\upload.php on line 5
```

Comment: `/uploads/` would indicate it's on the server root folder. Did you mean `uploads/`

Comment: I removed the first forward slash and now I'm actually getting the following errors:

**Warning: move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\wamp\www\TouchKiosk-ver2\php\upload.php on line 5**

and

**Warning: move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php5F6F.tmp' to 'uploads/' in C:\wamp\www\TouchKiosk-ver2\php\upload.php on line 5**

Comment: Add a file name to the target then :)

Comment: Please don't dump large errors or code to the comments. Update your OP with the additional information.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question to reflect this

Comment: I already answered why this was happening 5 minutes ago, have you done what my answer suggests?

Comment: I did, sorry it took so long to answer back, I'm accepting the answer you provided.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, if the folder is in the same directory as the script, you do not need to begin with a backslash.

Also, you don't use your own `$path` variable, you still use `$target` with no file name. In your code, change `move_uploaded_file` to use `$path` instead.

```
$target = "uploads/";
$path = $target.basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
if($_POST["upload"]){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $path)){
        echo "The file has been uploaded.";
    }
    else{
        echo "There was an error.";
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the first forward slash and now I'm actually getting the following errors: Warning: move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\wamp\www\TouchKiosk-ver2\php\upload.php on line 5 and Warning: move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php5F6F.tmp' to 'uploads/' in C:\wamp\www\TouchKiosk-ver2\php\upload.php on line 5

I'm also using $target in the move_uploaded_file function, that was  a typo.

Comment: As stated in my answer, you aren't using your path variable, you're using target. Your target variable doesn't include the file name.

Comment: Ah, so I need to use path then.  Sorry, I misread what you wrote.